# How to install IIS Admin Service on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: iis, windows-10, iis-10

I am trying to install TFS 2010 on my Windows 10 Pro box. It fails during the Readiness Checks, saying:

Error   [ Application Tier ] TF255151: Service is not installed: IIS Admin Service
Error   [ Application Tier ] TF255397: Windows Authentication has not been configured as a role service in Internet Information Services (IIS). Team Foundation Server requires that Windows Authentication is installed as one of the role services in IIS.

I cannot find IIS Admin Service anywhere. How do I install this service on Windows 10 IIS 10?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you installing TFS 2010? It's no longer supported and there have been 4 major releases in the past 7 years.

Comment: Client makes the rules, not me

Comment: I would expect you to encounter issues running an ancient version of TFS on a modern OS. Try an OS that was available in 2010.

Comment: I don't want to run my whole development platform back to an earlier OS for one program for one client. The client has TFS 2010 running on Windows 10 boxes, so it is possible. I just need an answer to my original question

Comment: Default IIS installation does not enable Windows authentication. Go to control panel and enable that.